# How can I achieve 3 boxes on top of each other using Nextjs Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add / style 3 boxes stacked on top of each other and then attach an image to it as such

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVdIo.png

I was able to achieve this but it's leaning side ways

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl0Zz.png

```
   <div className='flex flex-col box-border rounded strok h-60 w-48 p-4  border-2 ...'>
          <div className=' box-border rounded strok h-32 w-32 p-4 border-8 bg-black ...'>
            <div className=' box-border rounded strok h-32 w-32 p-4 border-8 bg-black ...'>
              <div className=' box-border rounded strok h-32 w-32 p-4 border-8 bg-black ...'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to implement that:

```html
<!-- Background -->
<div class="mx-auto h-[500px] w-[500px] flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-500 relative p-[10px]">
  <!-- Boxes container -->
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="relative mt-4 mx-4 h-full">
      <!-- Boxes stacked behind -->
      <div class="absolute -bottom-4 scale-[0.85] origin-bottom inset-x-0 h-full w-full bg-white/40 backdrop-blur-md rounded-2xl"></div>
      <div class="absolute -bottom-2 scale-95 origin-bottom inset-x-0 h-full w-full bg-white/40 backdrop-blur-md rounded-3xl shadow-sm"></div>
      <!-- Box on top -->
      <div class="p-4 bg-white/60 backdrop-blur-md rounded-3xl h-full">
        <img class="rounded-[20px]" src="https://variety.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Rick-Astley-Never-Gonna-Give-You-Up.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/dmU2c4ai36

Answer (score 1):

You have all the boxes nested with padding. Since they're nested, they're considered children. The parents have padding. Consider having a parent with a position of relative and the 3 boxes having a position of absolute.

```
<div class="h-screen w-screen bg-gray-200 py-20 flex justify-center items-center sm:py-12">
 <div class="h-40 w-40 relative">
 <div class="rounded h-[150px] w-[150px] bg-red-700 absolute z-30 left-1"> 
 </div>
  <div class="rounded h-[150px] w-[134px] bg-slate-500 absolute z-20 top-3 left-3"></div>
 <div class="rounded h-[142px] w-[118px] bg-black absolute z-10 top-8 left-5"></div>
```

I made an example for you on tailwind playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/MJnaFMVio6

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.